# Programmatically apply classes to angularjs form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive to facilitate the adding of bootstrap classes at runtime to streamline the need to apply "form-group", "control-label" and "form-control".  This works perfectly as long as I don't try to include multiple levels at once, meaning that I cannot seem to make this work to include multiple divs in "form-group.  I have attached the code, raw HTML and processed HTML for review to see if someone might have some insight into how I might modify to make this tool meaningful.

Directive:

```
    (function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("ppac")
        .directive("formfix", formfix);

    var addClasses = function (element) {
        var input = element.querySelector("input, textarea, select");
        var type = input.getAttribute("type");
        if (type !== "checkbox" && type !== "radio") {
            input.classList.add("form-control");
        }

        var label = element.querySelector("label");
        label.classList.add("control-label");
        element.classList.add("form-group");
    };

    function formfix() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element) {
            addClasses(element[0]);
                }
        }
    }
})();
```

HTML Form:

```
<form name="contactForm" ng-submit="model.submit()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div formfix>
                <label for="firstName" class="col-md-2">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" ng-model="model.contact.firstName" />
                </div>
                <label for="lastName" class="col-md-2">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" ng-model="model.contact.lastName" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Processed HTML:

```
<form name="contactForm" ng-submit="model.submit()" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div formfix="" class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName" class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" ng-model="model.contact.firstName" class="ng-pristine ng-valid form-control ng-empty ng-touched">
                    </div>
                    <label for="lastName" class="col-md-2">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" ng-model="model.contact.lastName" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class to add class dynamically as the document says

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an
>   HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes
>   to be added.

**Reference**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass